# BitmapFactory.decodeFile works fine on emulator but fails on HTC desire

Tags: android, bitmap, android-emulator, decode

I don't understand the problem, why BitmapFactory.decodeFile works fine on emulator but fails on HTC desire. The following code:

```
File f = new File("/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA/");
File files[] = f.listFiles();

Bitmap b1 = null, b2 = null;
b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files[0].getPath());
b2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files[1].getPath());
```

It's simple, but the application stops unexpectedly on HTC desire.
Oh, I find the problem:

```
07-18 08:01:45.634: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(20637): 8045568-byte external allocation too large for this process.
07-18 08:01:45.634: ERROR/(20637): VM won't let us allocate 8045568 bytes
07-18 08:01:45.743: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20637): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

The images are too large, how to handle them? I need good quality images too.

Comment: Might be the path you are using ....check the same path is accessible in htc desire also.

Comment: You are trying to get 2 files from a array that consists of 1 file. files[1] doesnt exist. And I don't know for sure but I dont think you should hardcode any path's to an SD card because not everyone has an SD card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way of using external path is [getExternalStorageDirectory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)

Change your code to something like this.

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/100MEDIA/");
```

Comment: That is a known issue search for bitmap outofmemoryexception.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) object while decoding the file. Set inSampleSize to something like 2 or 4 depending on your screen resolution to get an optimum preview. What it does is that it downsamples the image so that it does not take too much memory.

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = 2;
Bitmap b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files[0].getPath(), opts);;
```